How do you evaluate $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{x^2 + 4}dx$?

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{x^2 + 4}dx$$

I don't really know how to even approach this question, I can't even find the antiderivative of it.
EDIT : I'm thinking about converting it into $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{1}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})(x^2 + 4)}dx$
and then
$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty }^{0} \frac{1}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})(x^2 + 4)}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})(x^2 + 4)}dx$
and then
$\displaystyle\lim_{t \to -\infty}\int_{t }^{0} \frac{1}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})(x^2 + 4)}dx + \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})(x^2 + 4)}dx $
but I have no idea what to do next.
EDIT 2: I'm thinking about making it into $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to -\infty}\int_{t }^{0} \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}dx + \lim_{t \to -\infty}\int_{t }^{0} \frac{\cot{(i)}}{(x^2 + 4)}dx + \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}dx + \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{0 }^{t} \frac{\cot{(i)}}{(x^2 + 4)}dx$
and I'm stuck again

Are there typos?

Why is there a minus sign on the exponent?

yes there is, sorry, I'm new to latex, I corrected it, thank you for taking a look at my question

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.

Is $\left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^{-1}\right)^2$ meant to be $\left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)\right)^{-2}$, or is it meant to be $\left(\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)\right)^2$? Because those are two very different things.

It seems like your integral does not converge. Since $\tan(x/b) = 0$ at infinitely many points and therefore there is an infinite number of poles. Also your edit seems to go from having $\tan(x/b)$ to having $\tan(x/2).$ Is one of these a mistake?

sorry, I fixed the question, it is tan(x/2), not tan(x/b) and it is meant to be $(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})) ^ {2}$, thank you all so much

That makes it very different and much more tractable.

Now that you've got the correct integral, the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) = \frac{2}{x^2 + 4}$ should strongly suggest a substitution that will solve everything.

Start by performing the substitution $u = x/2$
$$I =2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan^2(u)}{4u^2+4}du = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan^2(u)}{u^2+1}du$$
Performing integration by parts:
$$\frac12(\arctan^3(u)|_{-\infty}^{\infty}- 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan^2(u)}{u^2+1}du)$$
$$I=\frac{\pi^3}8 - 2I                $$
Thus,
$$I = \frac{\pi^3}{24}$$
